# How to extract only required data from console output of linux commands

Tags: linux, shell, grep, command, cut

After executing the given command `mc ilm rule ls myminio/receive` i get the below output..

```
    ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
    │ Expiration for latest version (Expiration)                                            │
    ├──────────────────────┬─────────┬────────┬──────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────┤
    │ ID                   │ STATUS  │ PREFIX │ TAGS │ DAYS TO EXPIRE │ EXPIRE DELETEMARKER │
    ├──────────────────────┼─────────┼────────┼──────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
    │ cf59qti8ufll86j92g │ Enabled │ -      │ -    │             90 │ false               │
    │ cf7701klgt9a0vts40 │ Enabled │ -      │ -    │             90 │ false               │
    │ cf7712tlgie49qo4p0 │ Enabled │ -      │ -    │             90 │ false               │
```

From which i want only the list of `ID` from this output how do i extract it..

My excepted output :

```
cf59qti8ufll86j92g  
cf7701klgt9a0vts40  
cf7712tlgie49qo4p0
```

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
command | perl -ne 'print if (s/^\s*\S+\s+([a-z0-9]{18})\s.*$/\1/)'
```

Comment: This returns nothing @dimich

Comment: @AKSHAYKADAM I copied your example of program output to `example.txt` and run `cat example.txt | perl -ne 'print if (s/^\s*\S+\s+([a-z0-9]{18})\s.*$/\1/)'` It prints exactly expected output. Are you sure your program print to stdout? Are you sure output is the same to tty and pipe? Try first `your_command | cat`